# span_tokenize gives generator object as output

Tags: nltk, tokenize, text-mining, stringtokenizer, nltk-book

I have written a simple piece of code to see exactly how the span_tokenize function works. Documentation for this can be found here: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html
Here is my piece of code

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize.api import StringTokenizer
sample = StringTokenizer()
sample.span_tokenize("Hulk is Boss")
```

The output is as follows:

```
<generator object StringTokenizer.span_tokenize at 0x113a7b258>
```

I can't understand why I am getting a generator object as an output when the expected output is tuple(int,int) as can be seen from nltk documentation

A nudge in the right direction is appreciated !!

Comment: Yes interesting! Why does `span_tokenize()` return a generator! That's not suppose to happen.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Issue raised on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1980